# Why is this object changed from binded component?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I have this simple situation in my Svelte project:

**REPL**: https://svelte.dev/repl/41112edc53e04d59ba9a824cc9e6cde3?version=3.48.0

- App.svelte:

```html
<script>
    import Comp from "./Comp.svelte";
    
    let obj = {hello: 'world'};
    
    $: console.log("obj in App:", obj)
</script>

<Comp bind:obj></Comp>
```

- Comp.svelte:

```html
<script>
    export let obj;
</script>

<h1>Hello {obj.hello}!</h1>
```

What I don't understand is why the `obj` in *App.svelte* is changed from the `Comp.svelte` the first time it renders.

You can see in the log:

[image]

I expect it not to be changed until I change it somehow.

Answer (score 4):

I think the logic is like this:

- Setting the `obj` property of `<Comp>` causes the property to be invalidated there
- Because the value is bound via `bind:obj`, an invalidation of the property causes an invalidation in `<App>` as well.
- The reactive statement is triggered again by this invalidation

If you use `<Comp {obj} />` instead, this does not happen.

In general I would not recommend relying on the precise number of times that reactive statements are called.

Comment: Yeah I know all this. Is there a way to avoid the initial invalidation? After all they are the same object. Even if I know JS don't think they are.

Comment: Not that I know of and as noted, that really should not matter.

Comment: For primitive values equality is checked on invalidation, so if you just pass `obj.hello`, the statement is triggered only once ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7b53bcec8c7e46af8fe5587b9fdc3a51?version=3.48.0)).